# Helper methods aren't accessable in views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello I am using rails 5 and I am tying to use helper methods.

The error I am getting is

```
NoMethodError in Pages#home
undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x007feb5210b7c0>:0x007feb52109d30>
```

I am trying to use logged_in? in my partial view navigation bar. What am I doing wrong, I have no clue what is going on and I feel like this should be working. All help is welcome and appreciated, thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tier-List</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if logged_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Create new article", new_article_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", login_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path%></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Application Controller

```
  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session{:user_id}) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def require_user
    if !logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = "You must be logged in to perform that action"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

PagesController.rb

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  def home
  @articles = Article.all
  end

def tierlist

  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because the typo problem. You can change `helper_method :logged_in?` to `helper_method :logged_in` or change `def logged_in` to `def logged_in?`. The method name and the arguments of `helper_method` should be the same.

Your `PagesController` should extend `ApplicationController`, so `PagesController` can have all the thing you set in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Hmm thanks changed them both to logged_in? and still giving the same error unfortunately

Comment: do you have a `pages_controller.rb`? please show me.

Comment: Your `PagesController.rb` should extend `ApplicationController.rb`:
`class PagesController < ApplicationController`

Comment: Now the error is : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#home

Comment: Couldn't find User with 'id'=#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007f7fd448cd20> and then it complains about def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session{:user_id}) if session[:user_id]
  end

Comment: `User.find(session{:user_id}) ` should be `User.find(session[:user_id])`

Comment: You are a life save friend! Do you have any idea why my navbar is  on the page twice now?

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` around `:user_id` should be `[:user_id]`. Because of this typo, your `current_user` method is broken, so then calling `!!current_user` in the `logged_in?` method is not giving the expected outcome. The pattern in the Application Controller that would work best is something like:

```
def current_user
  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user

def current_user?(user)
  current_user == user
end
```

And then in your View, you would have something like:

```
<% if current_user?(@user) %>
  #show stuff that only signed in Users see
<% end %>
```

Hopefully, that clears up your errors.